# ERROR 1241 (21000) and ERROR 1093 (HY000) preventing execution of MYSQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

am providing mysql query here:-

```
mysql> UPDATE tbl_driver SET active_flag=NULL WHERE Pk_driver_id = (SELECT Pk_driver_id FROM tbl_driver JOIN tbl_location ON tbl_driver.pk_driver_id = tbl_location.fk_driver_id WHERE updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND active_flag=1);



ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tbl_driver' for update in FROM clause
```

so i changed my subquery to select *:

```
mysql> UPDATE tbl_driver SET active_flag=NULL WHERE Pk_driver_id = (SELECT * FROM tbl_driver JOIN tbl_location ON tbl_driver.pk_driver_id = tbl_location.fk_driver_id WHERE updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND active_flag=1);



ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s).
```

Please help me to fix this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: i changed "UPDATE tbl_driver SET active_flag=NULL WHERE Pk_driver_id = (SELECT Pk_driver_id FROM......" Still error 1093, no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `INNER JOIN` instead of the subselect should make your update work:

```
UPDATE 
    tbl_driver 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_location 
ON 
    tbl_driver.pk_driver_id = tbl_location.fk_driver_id
SET tbl_driver.active_flag = NULL
WHERE
    updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE 
AND 
    tbl_driver.active_flag = 1;
```

MySQL has currently (version 5.6) a limitation for the [use of subqueries in UPDATE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html):

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Comment: Yes, it worked. thank you very much and can you please tell me why it did'nt worked on subquery?

Comment: @user3775378: It's because MySQL currently not permits such a subselect: _Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery._ I've edited this into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to match a `set` to single row value, what you want is to match it against all the values that come out in subselect even if it is single value all the time. `IN` is keyword that allows you to match value in the set.

```
UPDATE tbl_driver SET active_flag=NULL
WHERE Pk_driver_id IN (
    SELECT Pk_driver_id FROM tbl_driver
    JOIN tbl_location ON tbl_driver.pk_driver_id = tbl_location.fk_driver_id
    WHERE updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND active_flag=1);
```

Comment: Still returning same error: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tbl_driver' for update in FROM clause

Comment: i tried it also changed Subquery, "SELECT * FROM tbl_driver......" then it returning error: ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) Not working, please help me to fix this